# Adding a file to git, track changes but do not keep history

Tags: git

How do I tell git to track a file but only keep the latest change and not keep a history.

file structure is like

./bin/  <--- Want to only have the latest (or at maximum last two changes) (for size reasons).

./src/ <--- Want to remain tracking all the changes.

I want them in the repository as updating can be done in one step.

I would prefer something not in the lines of hosting them separately. So when a pull is done everyone has access to the latest assets. Instead of adding steps.

Is there a way of limiting the history of a file to only the last X changes of a file (example 1 to 4 changes)?

Comment: Assuming the content of `./bin` were compiled from stuff in `./src`, don't put them in git. If that is the case, you need no history for the binaries because the source revision fully specifies the binary. This is a misuse of git and it will come to bite you in outrageously long clone and pull times.

Comment: @msw I know I could place the binaries on another medium like ftp or http. But wanted to know if the unnecessary steps could be avoided. Opening the site, check if the file changed and then decide to download it or not. vs git pull and downloading the files when they have changed.One step for all files, vs many steps for each file.

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is rsync.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If that works on windows as well, then it might be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (quite) do that, for one fairly simple reason:  **A commit is represented as a cryptographic checksum of the complete snapshot of all the files it contains, plus some metadata about who made the commit, when, and with what history.**  The "history" part is stored as some number of parent IDs—usually just one—which are also cryptographic checksums.

Since the checksum of a later commit incorporates the checksum of its parent commit(s), if you were to attempt to modify some earlier commit—for instance, to drop old compiled binaries that you no longer want to retain—the result would be a new, different commit ID for this new, different commit (that has no attached binaries).  You would then have to modify every subsequent commit: first you'd get its child (or one of its children, if it has more than one).  You would copy everything in that commit, including *its* binaries—you're retaining these—but you'd change the parent ID to use the new parent ID for the new commit you made that lacks binaries.  You'd then switch everyone from using the old child to the new child, which requires copying any additional commits that are children of that child, and so on.

In essence, you're rewriting ("rebasing") every single "down-chain" commit every time you rewrite one "up-chain" commit, because each commit records its entire history, and you're replacing some history with some other, different history.

It *is* possible to do this constant rebasing, but it will be painful as you'll be fighting with git's usage model.

There is another alternative but you already ruled it out:

> I would prefer something not in the lines of hosting them separately

If you allow it back in, though, you get a system where your commit snapshot contains the sources and—instead of the actual binaries—a unique identifier saying "these go with this other set of binaries", which you can store elsewhere.  You then have the option to make this a git repository of its own, which you can (but don't have to) call a "submodule".  You can just have any valid URL here if you don't want to use git submodules.  If you make this URL unique—e.g., by adding a unique checksum (SHA-1, MD5, etc) of the binaries—you can detect cases where the binaries are no longer available, having been deleted to due age.

(I actually would not recommend this—it's usually better not to store these binaries at all, really—but it becomes an option if you're willing to use two URLs instead of just one.  There's no requirement to use git submodules, and if you *do* use submodules you will need to make your commits in the binary repository independent, rather than parent/child related, by putting each commit on its own unique orphan branch, or stand-alone tag.  That will allow you to delete "aged-out" commits without affecting any other commits.)

Comment: Some assets are not code. So there is no way around it. Still you did gave me an idea on how to tack the problem on a less than optimum way, but good enough.

Answer (score -4):

Why the hell youvare using git, Man, git has been created for that history issue!
Or I got it wrong...
You can delete git and init from the first step, or if you want to clone only the last version, add --depth=1 to the clone command...